# What is actuall class for structural type scala syntax definition?

Tags: scala

Example:

```
type T = MyClass {def someMethod:String}
```

Does it mean for compiler creation of trait like "`trait AnonTrait extends MyClass {def someMethod:String}`"? Or it is done via other compiler mechanism?
My question was what is actually hidden by this Type syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't hide the creation of a type. Basically it masks use of reflection to check your structural constraints at compile time and to invoke someMethod at runtime.

For instance, if you have:

```
class Foo(t: MyClass {def someMethod:String}) {
    def CallSomeMethod = t.someMethod
}
```

this means the constructor for your Foo class accepts a t of type MyClass that also has a someMethod (where the someMethod could be mixed into MyClass via a trait).
You could have:

```
class MyClass {}
trait WithSomeMethod {def someMethod = "hello"}
```

and you could then create Foo like this:

```
val mc = new MyClass with WithSomeMethod
val foo = new Foo(mc)
println(foo.CallSomeMethod) // prints "hello"
```

now, when you create `new Foo(mc)` the compiler uses reflection to check that mc is a MyClass that also has a someMethod. The actual call `foo.CallSomeMethod` works via reflection as well.

Now (bear with me, I'm getting to your actual question...) doing as you did:

```
type T = MyClass {def someMethod:String}
```

is only creating a type alias, not a concrete type. Once you have T defined that way, you can define Foo as:

```
class Foo(t: T) {
    def CallSomeMethod = t.someMethod
}
```

this is equivalent to the definition of Foo given previously. You've just created an alias T that can be reused in other places where you might have used `MyClass {def someMethod:String}`. No actual T type is generated and the compiler still uses reflection whenever you refer to T, to check the structural constraint that it does have a someMethod defined, and still generates code based on reflection to invoke someMethod.

Comment: Thanks, so usage of such structural constraint as slow as reflection in java? And trait is better choice in those light.

Comment: yes, structural types have a performance impact due to reflection.

Answer (score 3):

It does not create a Trait, it only a type alias which means that each time your refer to `T`, you refer in fact to `MyClass {def someMethod:String}`. However, you can override type declaration with a trait:

```
trait A

class B {
  type T <: A
}

class SubB {
  trait T extends A
}
```

Comment: My question was what is actually hidden by this Type syntax.

Comment: An my answer was: a type alias.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this: a class does not have an structural type. The type of a class is always a class. A trait produces an interface. A singleton object's type is a class as well.

And where do structural types appear? *As types to parameters and variables.*

For example, I can say `def f(s: { def size: Int })`, or `val r: { def close(): Unit }`.

Now, how do these types appear as bytecode? Like any other type not supported by JVM (such as Java's own generics), they are *erased*.

So, as far as everyone else (ie, not Scala) is concerned, the types of `s` and `r` above are `java.lang.Object`.

For Scala itself, some additional information is stored in an annotation, that gives the exact information about these types as Scala understands them.